# regex to extract a string between 5th and 6th colon without space

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am working on a regex to extract the string between 5th and 6th string. I need to extract it without space as space is in between colons. Below is a sample from which I have to extract

> Abc Cloud : Xyz : Windows : Non Prod : Silver : ATC123XYZ : AQW Service is Down

I have tried `: (.+?):` however it returns : Xyz :,: Non Prod : and : ATC123XYZ :. What I want is only ATC123XYZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```regex
^(?:[^:]+\s*:\s*){5}([^:\s]+)
```

### Demo

**Explanation:**

```
^                 from the start of the input
(?:               match (but don't capture)
    [^:]+\s*:\s*  any term followed by :
){5}              match exactly 5 of these
([^:\s]+)         then match AND capture the 6th term
```

The term you want would be available in the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. I was trying to understand this, m getting it in bits and pieces. It will be great for many like us, if you can decode it step by step.